# Displaying specific data from a mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have already build a functioning login page which redirects the user the index.php file. This is the table that holds the username and password for each user:

```
user_id    username   password    email                 wage
1          johnsmith  jsmith99    jsmith@gmail.com      100
2          davidscott dscott95    davidscott@gmail.com  90
```

When the user logs in (by entering the correct combination of username and password), it redirects them to the index page where i would like to display the wage for that user.

The database is called **user_registration** and the table is called **users**

this is the php code that i have at the moment but it keeps returning errors:-

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';
$loginUsername = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];

$query=mysql_query("SELECT `wage` FROM `users` WHERE username = $loginUsername");

$result = mysql_query($query);
while($person = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<h1>" . $person['wage'] . "</h1>";  
}

?>
```

This is the error I get:

**Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\index.php on line 85**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running the query in $query, then running it AGAIN in $result

Try

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';
$loginUsername = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];

$query=mysql_query("SELECT `wage` FROM `users` WHERE username='$loginUsername'");

while($person = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo "<h1>" . $person['wage'] . "</h1>";  
}

?>
```

I recommend looking into encrypting your passwords (unless the above was just for our benefit)

Comment: still getting the same error - im not sure if the actual query is correct?

Comment: @SAMETHEMAN999 try echoing $loginUsername and make sure its populated

Comment: how do i do that? im fairly new to coding in php

Comment: @SAMETHEMAN999 before the $query line add

    `echo "Username: " . $loginUsername;` - does it list the username?

Comment: yes, it just displays the username ontop of the error

Comment: Is it displaying the actual username, or just Username:<blank> - and does the username actually exist in the database?

Comment: it does exist on the database^

Comment: Try the following to get the error: `$query=mysql_query("SELECT wage FROM users WHERE username='$loginUsername'") or die('Invalid query: ' .mysql_error());`

Comment: YES! That is it, i had not put the single speech marks around the $loginUsername! - it now works!, thank you @eXplicit for your help!

Comment: No problem - I had missed it in my original answer but edited shortly after, you maybe copied in the few seconds in between.

Comment: yeah, i saw that you had edited it and that you had put them in, so i did the same and voila! - Thank you again, i have been struggling on this for hours and hours!